# Why $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int _{[0,1]}\delta _\varepsilon =1/2$ and not $1$ if $\delta (A)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_A \delta _\varepsilon $?

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-delta

I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980372/understand-delta-function-why-do-me-write-int-delta-xdx-instead-of/2980432?noredirect=1#comment6151121_2980432) a question a Dirac $\delta $ function, and Surb in Hamza Boulahia answers says that $$\delta (A)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0 }\int_A \delta _\varepsilon (x)dx,$$
for $$\delta _\varepsilon (x)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon }\boldsymbol 1_{[-\frac{\varepsilon }{2},\frac{\varepsilon }{2}]}(x).$$
If this is true, then for example $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{[0,1]}\delta _\varepsilon (x)dx=1$$
since $\delta ([0,1])=1$. But when I do my calculation, I get $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{[0,1]}\delta _\varepsilon =\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_0^{\frac{\varepsilon }{2}}\frac{1}{\varepsilon }dx=\frac{1}{2}\neq 1,$$ so is this definition for $\delta $ function wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed wrong to assert $\delta(A)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_A\delta_\varepsilon$.  The $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\,\mathrm{d}\delta=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\delta_\varepsilon$ pairing is for $f$ continuous, which your $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ fails.

Alternatively, view $\delta_\varepsilon$ as a sequence of probability measures and we take $\delta$ to be the distribution limit.  We have $\delta(A)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\delta_\varepsilon(A)$ for any set $A$ such that $\delta(\partial A)=0$ by Portmentau's theorem, but obviously $\delta(\partial[0,1])=\delta(\{0,1\})=1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there a way to construct the $\delta $ measure with a sequence of probability measure $(\delta _\varepsilon )_\varepsilon $ ? Something as $$\nu_\varepsilon (A)=\int_A \delta _\varepsilon(x)dx $$ is a measure, and we set $\nu(A)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_A \delta _\varepsilon (x)dx$. But unfortunately it's not the dirac measure. But can we construct the dirac measure as well ? Because it says on wikipidia that the diract measure can be seen as the limit in distribution of $\delta _\varepsilon =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}|\varepsilon |}e^{-x^2/\varepsilon ^2}$,

Comment: But I can't prove that $\delta (A)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_A\frac{1}{\varepsilon \sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2/\varepsilon ^2}dx$. Is it possible to prove it ?